# Change string from get response to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox I want an autofill feature for but it's a dynamic on so that data in the auto fill must from from a server. I got everything already going I figure I would use the auto fill function from jquery library but the issue is I can't load the text from my get as an array properly...

Here is the code

```
jQuery(".search-form-box").on("input", function() {
    var box = $(this);
    var min = box.data("autocomplete-min");
    var searchLink = box.data("autocomplete-url");
    var autocomplete;
    if (box.val().length >= min) {
        $.get(searchLink + box.val(), function(data) {
            autocomplete = [ data.substring(data.indexOf("[") + 1, data.indexOf("]")) ];
            box.autocomplete({
                source : autocomplete
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Now the get response returns a webpage in html so I parsed it... here is what the HTML is

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <pre> ["Software","Hardware","Malware"]</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

So I parsed it by [ and ] as you can see. To get the inside "Software","Hardware","Malware"

How would I parse that into an array that can be used as the sources for my box?

Comment: autocomplete = data.substring(data
                                                .indexOf("[") + 1, data
                                                .indexOf("]")).split(',')

Comment: @juvian I don't need to " in my output? from the get response?

Comment: '"Software","Hardware","Malware"'.split(",") gives an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let jQuery do the work for you:

```
var pre = $(data);
```

Gets just the `<pre>` element and its context.  `html` and `body` are ignored.

```
var pretext = pre.text();
```

Gets the contents (the array string).

```
var arr = JSON.parse(pretext);
```

Parses the string into an array (if, like your example above, it's valid JSON).

```js
var data = '<html><head></head><body><pre> ["Software","Hardware","Malware"]</pre></body></html>';

var pre = $(data);

var pretext = pre.text();

var arr = JSON.parse(pretext);

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = '<html><head>\
</head>\
<body>\
<pre> ["Software","Hardware","Malware"]</pre>\
\
</body></html>\
  ';
var arr =   JSON.parse(
  str.replace(/[^[]*/ , '').replace(/(])(.*)/ , '$1')
  )

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr)
```